# MediaInfo get subtitles more sensibly

Tags: c#, arrays, iteration, mediainfo

I making windows forms application with MediaInfo Wrapper and I can't find any good solution to get all subtitles and put them in to the array or string.

Because if I hard code **subtitle1**, **subtitle2**, **subtitle3**, **subtitle4** etc... and there is no subtitles at all or that much I hard coded, I got error:

`Input string was not in a correct format`

So how I can get subtitles and list them in string or array nicely like this: **Eng**, **Fra**, **Spa** without hard code and above error. (I got this error everytime if there is no subs).

My code:

```
// Hardcoding (possible) subtitles...
string subOne = MI.Get(StreamKind.Text, 0, "Language/String3");
string subTwo = MI.Get(StreamKind.Text, 1, "Language/String3");
string subThree = MI.Get(StreamKind.Text, 2, "Language/String3");

string subtitlesCount = MI.Get(StreamKind.General, 0, "TextCount"); // Count how many subtitles included

string subtitles = "";

int subtitlesInt = Int32.Parse(subtitlesCount);

// Trying to find better solution over here...
if (subtitlesInt >= 1 && subtitlesInt < 2)
{
   subtitles = subOne;
} else if (subtitlesInt >= 1 && subtitlesInt <= 2)
{
   subtitles = subOne + "," + subTwo;
} else {
   subtitles = "";
}

 //var subsArray = subtitles.Split(',');
 //subtitles = String.Join(",", subsArray);

 // Display mediainfo data to textbox
 string data = "";

 data += "Subtitles: " + subtitles + "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is not tested nor compiled. Just an idea how you can do this based on your code.

```
string subtitles = "";
int subtitlesInt = Int32.Parse(MI.Get(StreamKind.General, 0, "TextCount"));

for(int i = 0, i < subtitlesInt; i++)
{
    subtitles += MI.Get(StreamKind.Text, i, "Language/String3") + ",";
}
```